# Hostname resolving to old ip

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm in a Windows network.

Recently i replaced one of the machines in my network; it has the hostname 'server1'.

I put a new machine on its place, with the same hostname, 'server1'.

The problem is, when i try to ping this new machine with the command

```
ping server1
```

It resolves to the IP of the old machine, not the new one. The old ip does not exists in my network anymore.

How can i 'flush' this name resolution, so the new machine hostname becomes active ?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps `ipconfig /flushdns` command might do the trick?

Comment: Check your DNS Records on the Windows server, a static route could have been created there, we have multiple records for file servers so it could be someone created the record and it needs to be updated.

Comment: @delphirules No problem! added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Windows Server check your DNS Records.

1. Log on to Windows server 2008 R2 DNS server computer with domain
   admin or enterprise admin credentials.
2. From the desktop screen, click Start.
3. From the Start menu, go to Administrative Tools > DNS.
4. On DNS Manager snap-in, from the console tree in the left pane, double-click  to expand the DNS server name.
5. From the expanded list,
       double-click Forward Lookup Zones. From the displayed zones list,
       click to select the DNS zone for which Host (A) DNS record is to be
        modified

Look for a record which in your case is called 'server1'
If there is one modify the IP address to the new static IP,

Someone May have added a Static Route called "Server1" and it might just need to be updated.